# VirtualBox machine starts, but not running

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Running an Ubuntu Server 15.10 host, I have a guest VM registered.

Entering: `vboxmanage startvm [NAME] --type gui`

I get: `VM [NAME] has been successfully started`.

Immediately after, I enter: `vbox manage controlvm [NAME] poweroff`.

But I get: `VBoxManage: error: Machine '[NAME]' is not currently running`.

Ideas?

Comment: This seems to be VirtualBox error [#14846](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14846) (nothing useful over there, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

I got in the similar situation, was looking for hours, my case was that I needed to restart virtual box daemon

```
/etc/init.d/virtualbox reload
```

Comment: Current version (6.1.26) doesn't seem to support `reload`, only `force-reload`, and that didn't help in my case.